# Image not displaying in chrome

Tags: html

I want to show.Image from this path //dan/images/img 12.jpg Which is working on I.E.

I want to display it in ,chrome like it is displaying in IE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply drag the image directly into your browser, 
 in addition to display the picture,   it will also show the path.

And so you should have something like this :
[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AR7Ko.png)

Now you juste have to copy/paste the url and insert it into a

```
<img src="//C:/Users/Utilisateur/Desktop/visuels%20pampilles/8950_101_Pirouette.jpg" />
```

Should work..

Comment: When I drag, in New tab it is showing, but not with src of Img tag with same path

Comment: He wants to see it  in html,not just see the content of the picture

Comment: Martin, simple image is not showing in chrome while accessing this link.

Comment: It's just a screenshot of what it should look like, you're not supposed to copy/paste my link in your browser... Ofc you can't access it since the file's  on my computer..But since i don't really know what you want here, i can't help you much... unless you tell us about your problem a bit more precisely

Comment: Ok when I am dragging it works but when I copied se url with img tag it doesn't work..

Comment: This is Again not working with chrome, working with ie

Comment: Can you please make fiddle of file a. jpg in c: drive with chrome

Comment: here you go https://jsfiddle.net/eag9rz2n/ You can't get a .jpg from your c: drive from fiddle, the jpg needs to be on a webserver

Comment: When I inspect and copy. Url  it is working in New tab.. and not showing in Img chrome..

Answer (score 0):

Try to go incognito .There  browser maybe stored it in cache

Comment: I am displaying it from network. Not c: ... for network what I should write ?

Comment: Can you please make fiddle of file a. jpg in c: drive with chrome